# Deserialize keyvalue string to object

Tags: c#, key-value

Hi can anybody help me out from this.

I have an HTML page. This page contains Textboxes for FirstName,MiddleName, LastName, etc.

On button clcik of this HTML page i am calling a javascript function. Here i am getting all the HTML page contaols and its value using JQuery Serialization. Then passing this values to my WCF service hosted in server.

This service will parse this string into corresponding objects and save the values into the database.

So In HTMl page  i written the Javascript function like below:

```
pmamml.ButtonClick = function() {
var formData = $("#form1").serializeArray();
var stringJson;
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(formData) {
   stringJson=  JSON.stringify(formData)
});
//alert(stringJson);
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://URL/Service.svc/Update?formData=' + JSON.stringify(formData),
    error: pmamml.ajaxError,
    success: function(msg) {
        document.write(msg);
        //alert(msg);
    },
});},
```

And in WCF service i written:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/Update?formData={formData}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public string Update(string formData)
    {
        //   Here i am receiving formdata string as
        // formData = "[{\"name\":\"FirstName\",\"value\":\"Pankaj\"},{\"name\":\"MiddleName\",\"value\":\" \"},{\"name\":\"LastName\",\"value\":\"KUMAR\"}]";
    }
```

I wanna deserialize this string into List object or keyvaluepair or Dictionary any one of the above format.

So that i can save this value into database.

How can we do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually i am trying to get all the controls and its value in HTML page and passing this value to the WCF service. And this service will deserialize this values and save to the database.

Comment: So i write the JQuery in HTML page like below:

Comment: pmamml.ButtonClick = function() {
    var formData = $("#form1").serializeArray();
    var stringJson;
    $.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(formData) {
       stringJson=  JSON.stringify(formData)
    });
    //alert(stringJson);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://URL.com/Service.svc/Update entityName=Users&formData=' + JSON.stringify(formData),
        error: pmamml.ajaxError,
        success: function(msg) {
            document.write(msg);
            //alert(msg);
        },
    });
},

Comment: And in my WCF service i written the method which accepts 2 parameters as below.

Comment: Can you update your question please instead of adding comments - it's getting a little hard to follow what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: and it is "want to", tut, tut ;-)

Comment: [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/Update?entityName={entityName}&formData={formData}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public string Update(string entityName, string formData)
        {
            // CALL MLParser Method to Deserailize and Update Entity
            //var mlParser = new MLParser();
            //return "Hiiii";
            //return mlParser.Update(entityName, formData);
            return formData;

        } Here formData contails the name value pair string. so i wanna deserialize into objects or something.

Comment: So that i can save this data into database. Hope you understand. can anybody help me out.

Comment: This is the MSDN entry that explain how to deserialize a JSON object. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx. I have already done it for lists and dictionnaries of object also, but it's been some months and I cannot find the snippet of code. If nobody answers before tonite, I'll post the code snippet here. It's pretty straight forward. .Net does all the job for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yup i got the solution

This is my updated JQuery

```
pmamml.ButtonClick = function() {
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
var stringJson = JSON.stringify($('#form1').serializeObject());
var Userdata = "formData=" + stringJson;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://URL/Service.svc/Update?' + Userdata,
    error: pmamml.ajaxError,
    success: function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (response = true) {
            //alert(response);
            alert("Data Updated Successfully");
        }
    }
});
```

}

In above method formData will pass the JSON string like below:
{ "FirstName":"Raja","MiddleName":"Raja","LastName":"Kumar"}.

And in my WCF Service, converted this JSON string to Object.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/Update?formData={formData}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public bool Update(string formData)
    {
        var mlParser = new MLParser();
        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer s = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

            var InfoList = s.Deserialize<Users>(formData);

        return mlParser.Update(InfoList);
    }



public class Users
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

This is working fine.

Thnak you all for your kind response.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it would be to split it into an array using RegEx, matching \"([^\"]*).

**update** Given you are sending it to a web service, it should just be configured as Json to deserialize it automatically

Comment: No it wouldn't be the easiest, neither the smartest way of doing. .Net has all the objects for serializing and deserializing list and dictionnaries to and from JSON. ( I won't put you -1 though... )

Comment: @StephaneRolland Good point - I forget you can use them yourself. Want to edit my post? I am iPadding at the moment so it would be too risky

Comment: thank you all for posting. please update if you know nayother way.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will give you your stringdata seperated into workeable pieces, as displayed below.

```
        // new list 
        var l = new List<string>();
        // original data
        var s = "[{\"name\":\"FirstName\",\"value\":\"Raja\"},{\"name\":\"MiddleName\",\"value\":\"Raja \"},{\"name\":\"LastName\",\"value\":\"KUMAR\"}]";
        // clean up and split in larger parts
        var d = s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2).Replace("\\", "").Replace("\"", "").Replace("}", "").Split('{');
        // Split in final entries and add to list
        var sb = new char[2] { ',', ':' };
        foreach (var r in d) { l.AddRange(r.Split(sb, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

// Contents of the List will be

name

FirstName

value

Raja

name

MiddleName

value

Raja

name

LastName

value

KUMAR

// The code is not very robust yet, e.g. you need to check your inputstring is not empty